# Getting 2 question marks when I typeset code

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, greek

Only in the last line, my output shows up as ?? right before \beta in the last fraction.

```
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}
\maketitle % showing both title and author, plus and automatic date

\includegraphics{proof9}

Applying trigonometric functions to the larger right triangle, we get
\begin{align}
\sin(\alpha+\beta)&=\frac{\sin\beta+a}{\cos\alpha+b}\\
&=\frac{\sin\beta+\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos(\alpha+\beta)}}{\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\cos(\alpha+\beta)}}\\
\textit{and}\\
\cos(\alpha+\beta)&=\frac{\cos\beta}{\cos\alpha+b}\\
&=\frac{\cos\beta}{\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha\frac{\sin(\alpha+‌​\beta)}{\cos(\alpha+‌​\beta)}}.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello again, please don't delete questions when you get an answer, I was working on a fuller answer at the time. (Admittedly, I was about to give up because it's getting late and I didn't fancy researching a nicer way to produce that "and" there, you should at the very least add a `\notag` so it isn't numbered, but I think `\intertext{}` would suit you better, only it has quite big gaps above and below.) Anyway

Comment: Somehow a zero-width space has been inserted in your source code. This is the error message I get `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ​ (U+200B)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.24 \end{align}
                
?` I don't know how you're writing the code, but you should probably try deleting the last bit and retype.

Comment: The errant character is, as you say, just before `\beta` -- both `\beta`s on that line actually

Comment: @Au101 Sorry, I didn't know how to mark that I no longer need an answer to my previous question as I had figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Kacey That is not a reason to delete your question! Questions are not just for you. They are for anybody with the same issue or interest. If everybody did that, all the solutions to problems would be erased. The site would consist solely of unanswered questions about unsolved problems.

Comment: Well that's alright, but next time, just leave the question. You'll get some rep, you might get some fuller answers with other recommendations that you can take or leave and the site gets to keep its content and its contributors don't lose any of their efforts. Once you get an answer you can accept it. In general nobody minds chiming in with something useful even if the actual question has been solved in one way, they can always come along with something else. Also in general, as cfr says, you should leave the question so others can benefit it (although yours was very specific I'll grant you)

Comment: In this case, though, if @Au101 's comment solves the problem and Au101 agrees, it might make sense to delete this as it isn't really a TeX issue in that case.

Comment: If no proper answer is written, but the question is solved in the comments, the question will usually be closed by the community anyway, but we like to leave them open for a while and when they're closed all the content is still there so we don't lose anything

Comment: @Au101 Often people are asked to turn comments into answers, though. I think that is even more common. (Just an impression, though - I don't have stats.)

Comment: @cfr The other one was, if I'm right, a `{` too many. This one, eh, I don't mind, it's actually quite a common issue, some stray unicode character finds its way in. What should be a `-` is actually a minus sign, microsoft word puts in some fancy line ending character or this or that or the other :P

Comment: @cfr How is this question not a TeX issue?

Comment: @Au101 The retyping the code worked and got rid of the question marks.

Comment: @Au101 The trouble is, it is so hard to write about problems caused by invisible characters! Maybe we should have a standard goto question, though. (Do we have one?) Editing plain text files in Word is surely asking for trouble anyway. `<rant class=ms, name=word>`Word wouldn't know plain text if it came up and hit it over the head with 'I"M PLAIN TEXT< GET IT??'. `</rant>`

Comment: It is really an input issue. Typically a copy-paste issue. That might be editor related, but it is more likely to do with how copy-paste works on your system.

Comment: @Kacey Well it's arguably not a TeX issue, it's a code input issue, in as much as your TeX is fine, you just have a stray character in there. It's like - what's it like? It's like you're cooling your pie on the windowsill and some fly comes through the window and lands on it. Now that's not so much a cooking question as a - how do I keep bugs off my stuff question

Comment: @Au101 I see. I'll try to learn the ways of asking the right questions in the right places.

Comment: @Kacey Don't worry about it! I hope you don't feel lectured to :) Trust me, your first question was fine, I just hate to see good questions deleted (especially when I've put a little time into them) but you didn't know, don't sweat it! This one, again, you've asked in the right place, but it *might* be acceptable to close/delete this question simply because it's not the TeX that's wrong, but your input. But again, it's TeX input and it takes some experience to spot the problem. I would leave it, but it's obviously a fringe case. Happy TeXing and welcome to the site. Stick around

Comment: (Just maybe be a li'l less trigger happy with that there delete button if you can :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are zero width characters before the beta.

If you paste that section of text into (for example) here

https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html

you will see

```
  U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A     a
  U+006c LATIN SMALL LETTER L     l
  U+0070 LATIN SMALL LETTER P     p
  U+0068 LATIN SMALL LETTER H     h
  U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A     a
  U+002b PLUS SIGN     &plus; \mathplus +
  U+200c ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER     &zwnj;
  U+200b ZERO WIDTH SPACE     &ZeroWidthSpace; &NegativeVeryThinSpace; &NegativeThinSpace; &NegativeMediumSpace; &NegativeThickSpace;
  U+005c REVERSE SOLIDUS     &bsol; \backslash \textbackslash
  U+0062 LATIN SMALL LETTER B     b
  U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E     e
  U+0074 LATIN SMALL LETTER T     t
  U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A     a
```

showing that you have U+200C and U+200B at that position, which you need to delete.